# How i can round to the nearest 60 sec interval in MySQL

Tags: mysql, time, numbers, rounding

I got a table that have records of calls. The detail have the the phone_number and call_time in **milliseconds**. Which could be the SQL statement to have a column with the rounded call_time to the **nearest top 60th** second? Example:

```
phone_number | call_time | rounded_time
=====================================
787-468-8965 |  45786    |   60
787-564-8945 | 128907    |   180
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Convert to minutes.
- Using the [`CEILING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling) function to round up to the next minute.
- Convert back to seconds.

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW yourview AS
SELECT
    CEILING(call_time / 60000) * 60,
    -- etc...
```